# Putting a string and calling a method in the same line

Tags: ruby

I have a class called Fractions that takes in a numerator and a denominator. It has three methods- frac, redfrac, dec- that print out the fraction, its reduced version, and its decimal form respectively.
As an example, if the numerator is 12 and the denominator is 4, I want to print out the result as so:

> Fraction: 12/4
>   Reduced Fraction: 3
>   Fraction as Decimal: 3.0

My current code after my Fractions class is as follows

```
a = Fractions.new(numer, denom)

puts "Fraction:"
a.frac
puts "Reduced Fraction:"
a.redfrac
puts "Fraction as a Decimal:"
a.dec
```

which prints out

> Fraction:
>   12/4
>   Reduced Fraction:
>   3
>   Fraction as a Decimal:
>   3.0

How do I print the text as I want it? I tried doing

```
puts "Fraction:" + a.frac
```

but this does not work because I cannot interpolate a string with my calling of the method.

Comment: Don't confuse what `irb` prints out with what Ruby will print out when the script is run. The `irb` tool runs as a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop) which prints a result for each statement you give it regardless of if you want it printed for real.

Answer (score 2):

`"Fraction:" + a.frac` is not using string interpolation - it is using the + operator and trying to add a Fixnum to a String, which is impossible.

To use String interpolation, you can do it like this:

```
puts "Fraction: #{a.frac}"
```

You could also do this:

```
puts "Fraction: " + a.frac.to_s
```

Which converts the Fixnum to a string before adding them together

Do the same for the reduced version and the decimal form respectively.

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation for more information (RubyMonk also has a good explanation of string interpolation, but appears to be down).

Comment: Neither of these work and they both print out
```
15
/3
Fraction:
5
Reduced Fraction: 
5.0
Fraction as a Decimal:
```

Comment: @SMW Unless `inspect` produces the same results as `to_s` you may get slightly different results. String interpolation uses the `to_s` method, but `irb` uses `inspect`.

Comment: Third way: `puts "Fraction: %s" % a.frac.to_s`.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do string concatenation with `+` operator because the return value of `a.frac` is not a string.

You could explicitly convert it to string with `.to_s` and change your line:

```
puts "Fraction:" + a.frac.to_s
```

or, you could use Ruby's string interpolation like this:

```
puts "Fraction: #{a.frac}"
```